# Is there abounded amount of actors in the same Service Fabric Actor app?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I wonder if in 'real life' and not just in theory, is there a max limit of the number of actors in the same app? Does it know to handle 500,000 actors in the same time? asume that I have the physical resources (cpu and memory)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The nice thing about [Actors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction) is that their lifecycle is managed. If they're not used, they are persisted and taken out of memory (garbage collected). So it's not a problem to have millions of Actors in your system.
See this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/use-actors-to-talk-to-millions/) for an example, an online game with millions of players.

Provided you think ahead of the resource requirements and partitioning, SF should scale well.

Comment: Thank you @LoekD for you answer. Do you know if Actors are also good for jbos scheduling for a million of jobs? there won't be any delays?

Comment: That really depends on what the job is (CPU / Memory / Disk requirements) and the amounts of available resources. Keeping track of millions of game players works, so your jobs could work as well.